# Is there a way to change flutter audio_video_progress_bar progress time while seeking?

Tags: flutter, audio, progress-bar, just-audio

I am currently in the process of building a music player app using the `just_audio` package that utilizes the `audio_video_progress_bar`. I have implemented it mostly according to the documentation.

The ProgressBar works entirely fine, and after seeking, the progress time is set accordingly to the new thumb location. However, the time only changes after the thumb is released, **whereas I would like it to more closely mimic other music apps, where the time changes while you move the thumb**, so as to be able to more closely choose, where you wish to seek to.

I have tried searching both SOF and Google, sadly finding no solutions. Is there anything I might be missing? Thanks for any help or pointers.

Here is the relevant code for the ProgressBar itself:

```
StreamBuilder<DurationState>(
  stream: _durationState,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    final durationState = snapshot.data;
    final progress = durationState?.progress ?? Duration.zero;
    final buffered = durationState?.buffered ?? Duration.zero;
    final total = durationState?.total ?? Duration.zero;
    return ProgressBar(
      progress: progress,
      buffered: buffered,
      total: total,
      onSeek: (duration) {
        _player.seek(duration);
      },
    );
  },
),
```

and for the Duration state:

```
class DurationState {
  const DurationState({this.progress, this.buffered, this.total});
  final Duration progress;
  final Duration buffered;
  final Duration total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use audio_video_progress bar's own time indicator which automatically reflect any changes in progress bar like this...
 `ProgressBar( . . ,timeLabelPadding: 5, timeLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(<anytextstyle>), //color etc timeLabelLocation: TimeLabelLocation.above, . . . .)`